# Предварительное объявление класса в заголовочных файлах

Tags: c++, классы, объявление

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
class ResourcePack
{
protected:
// something
};

class Player : ResourcePack
{
public:
// something
};
#endif
```

Render.h

```
#ifndef RENDER_H
#define RENDER_H

#include <vector>

class ResourcePack;
class Player : ResourcePack; // Синтаксическая ошибка

class Render
{
public:
    ::std::vector<Player>& rfvPlayer;
};

#endif
```

*Дополнительно - Machine.h*

```
#ifndef MACHINE_H
#define MACHINE_H

#include <vector>
#include "Player.h"

class Machine
{
public:
::std::vector<Player> vPlayer;
};
#endif
```

В последствии я собираю все заголовочные файлы в одном заголовочном файле.

```
#ifndef GAMEKERNEL_H
#define GAMEKERNEL_H

#include "Machine.h"
#include "Render.h"

// something

#endif
```

Как можно предварительно объявить класс Player в файле Render.h (так как он наследуется от класса ResourcePack, ничего не выходит)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При предварительном наследовании не указывают кто от кого наследуется. Просто слово class, имя класса и точка с запятой.

Comment: А в последствии, при инициализации ссылки rfvPlayer, не будет проблем? Ведь я 
 где-нибудь буду присваивать класс-наследник, а в файле Render.h он предварительно объявлен как самостоятельный класс.

Comment: нет, не будет. Но только в месте "присваивания" должно быть доступно полное определение класса.

Comment: спасибо Вам, понял